# How to express "not in dealing scope"?

Tags: expressions

For example, I send `A,B,C,D,E` to let computer program deal with it.

- A,B,C are in program job scope; the program will do it
- D,E are not in the job scope

I want to express this to let the client know. How can it be said better? Please guide me.

Here are my thoughts:

> This objects in not in my dealing scope: D..E
>
> This objects had been passed: D,E

Answer (score 1):

The details will vary depending on the context/domain, and answers in the computer/IT industry may vary from other domains. But, speaking generally, I believe the terms you are looking for are **in scope/out of scope**. For example:

> The following objects are in scope for the program: A, B, C
>
> The following objects are not in scope for the program: D, E

...as well as numerous variations:

> The following objects are out of scope for the program: D, E
>
> These objects are outside of the program's scope: D, E
>
> These objects are out of scope: D, E

Side note: I would avoid using D..E to mean "everything between D and E, inclusive" unless your audience is highly technical. It's accurate, just not understood outside the technical community. "Average" users will better understand "D-E" or even "D through E". Similarly, while you can *pass* objects and variables to a function or program, average end users won't understand what is meant. I would use words like "handled," "read," or "managed" instead.